# Tables relationship on mysql to calculate new field

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, query-optimization, large-data

I'll explain the structure I have, but first I'll tell what I need. I've got a table with forecasts and one with the data of what really happened. And I need to calculate the `forecast - happened` field. Both tables have the coordenates field (lon,lat), the date and the precipitation. Forecast has one more field which is the date the forecast was made.

```
class Real(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_real'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    lon  = Column(Integer,index=True)
    lat  = Column(Integer,index=True)
    date = Column(DATE,index=True)
    prec = Column(Integer)
       


class Forecast(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_forecast'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    
    real_id   = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('tbl_real.id'))
    date_pub  = Column(DATE,index=True)
    date_prev = Column(DATE,index=True)
    lon       = Column(Integer,index=True)
    lat       = Column(Integer,index=True)
    prec      = Column(Integer,)
   
class Error(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_error'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    
    forecast_id     = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('tbl_forecast.id'))
    real_id         = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('tbl_realizado.id'))
    error           = Column(Integer)
```

To insert data on `Error` I'm using:

```
def insert_error_by_coord_data(self,real_id,lon,lat,date,prec,session):

    ec_ext   = session.query(Forecast.id,Forecast.prec).filter((Forecast.lon == lon)&
                                 (Extendido.lat == lat)&
                                 (Extendido.date_prev == date)).all()
        
    data = list()
    for row in ec_ext:
            id = row[0]
            if session.query(Erro).get(id) is None:
                prev = comb[1]
                error = prev - prec
                data.append(Erro(id = id,
                                 ext_id = id,
                                 real_id = real_id,
                                 error= error))
            
        if len(data) > 0:
            session.bulk_save_objects(objects=data)
            session.commit()
            session.close()
```

Each forecast file has 40 `data_prev` and 25000 coordenates. And each real file has 25000 coordenates. It's been I think some 2 hours and I only got 80000 rows on `Error`. It started taking 1.03 s to insert a record and now it's 3.04s. I'm using 12 cpus with `multiprocessing`, if you think the mistake is here please point out and I can show the code, but I don't think it is.
The question is what should I do differently?

Comment: lat,lng as integers??

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL -- `SELECT ...` and `CREATE TABLE ...`

Comment: When I searched for a coordinate, I found no matches and it was because instead of being 50.2, it was 50.200000005 (I don't  actually remember how many zeroes it was)

Comment: `DECIMAL` solves that problem.  And gives you more precision.  1 degree of latitude is 69 miles (111km).